# Google PubSub with pull subscriber design flaw?

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, system-design

We are using googles steaming pull subscriber the design is as follows

[image]

We are doing

1. sending file from FE (frontend) to BE (backend)
2. BE converting that file to ByteArray and publishing to pubsub topic as message (so ByteArray going as message)
3. Topic sending that message to subscriber, subscriber converting the ByteArray to file again
4. that converted file subscriber sending to that tool
5. tool doing some cool stuff with file and notify the status to subscriber
6. that status going to BE and BE update the DB and sending that status to FE

Now in our subscriber when we receive message we are immediately acknowledge it and removing the listener of subscriber so that we don't get message any more
and when that tool done that stuff, it sending status to subscriber (we have express server running on subscriber) and

`after receiving status we are re-creating listener of subscriber to receive message`

**Note**

- that tool may take 1hr or more to do stuff
- we are using ordering key to properly distribute message to VM's

this code is working fine but my question is

- is there any flaw in this (bcz we r removing listener then again re creating it or anything like that)
- or any better option or GCP services to best fit this design
- or any improvement in code

**EDIT :**
Removed code sample

Comment: Some questions: Can you add the subscription in the schema? You forgot it (I'm sure you have only one, but just to be sure). Do all the process by some tool take 1H or so? What does limit the process? Why you can't process several messages in the same time (and thus you need to remove the listener)? how many VM do you expect in parallel to process all the incoming files?

Comment: Thanks for your time and consideration   
1. what do you mean by schema ?? (the code I given that is all We have, no extra thing)
2. no some process may take 2hr some may take 30m some may take 10 minutes also
3. that tool use that converted file so at a time it handle only one file and do stuff in VM
4. VM is depends on client some client can give 3 VM's some may give 1VM etc.

Comment: when we get message subscriber triger that tool , tool takes that converted file and do stuff so may be we cannot run that tool parallelly

Comment: Schema is the drawing that you put on top of your question. Is it possible to speed up the conversion process? For example, by adding CPUs? And how many memory (RAM) require your process? What the max file size?

Comment: ok got it  1. we have one subscription per client/user so one subscription may have two or more subscriber or one also (depend on client how many VM they can give ) 2. yes possible right now we have 32 or 16 GB ram and also good amount of CPU's (we r running windows) 3. max size will not be more then 2 or 3 MB mostly all the files are in KB's

Answer (score 1):

I would say that there are several parts of this design that are sub-optimal. First of all, acking a message before you have finished processing it means you risk message loss. What happens if your tool or subscriber crashes after acking the message, but before processing has completed? This means when the processes start back up, they will not receive the message again. Are you okay with requests from the frontend possibly never being processed? If not, you'll want to ack after processing is completed, or--given that your processing takes so long--persist the request to a database or to some storage and then acknowledge the message. If you are going to have to persist the file somewhere else anyway, you might want to consider taking Pub/Sub out of the picture and just writing the file to storage like GCS and then having your subscribers instead read out of GCS directly.

Secondly, stopping the subscriber upon each message being received is an anti-pattern. Your subscriber should be receiving and processing each message as it arrives. If you need to limit the number of messages being processed in parallel, use [message flow control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#config).

Also ordering keys isn't really a way to "properly distribute message to VM's." Ordering keys is only a means by which to ensure ordered delivery. There are no guarantees that the messages for the same ordering key will continually go to the same subscriber client. In fact, if you shut down the subscriber client after receiving each message, then another subscriber could receiving the next message for the ordering key since you've acked the earlier message. If all you mean by "properly distribute message" is that you want the messages delivered in order, then this is the correct way to use ordering keys.

You say you have a subscription per client, then whether or not that is the right thing to do depends on what you mean by "client." If client means "user of the front end," then I imagine you plan to have a different topic per user as well. If so, then you need to keep in mind the 10,000 topic-per-project limit. If you mean that each VM has its own subscription, then note that each VM is going to receive every message published to the topic. If you only want one VM to receive each message, then you need to use the same subscription across all VMs.

In general, also keep in mind that Cloud Pub/Sub has at-least-once delivery semantics. That means that even an acknowledged message could be redelivered, so you do need to be prepared to handle duplicate message delivery.

Comment: Thanks for your time 1. when the process fails, that TOOL sends status failed to the subscriber (which runs the server) and that subscriber sends status to FE user/client that please resend that file again (so all process will repeat again)  2.we want to distribute (Load balance) the message in order they came from user to VM's 3.client is user of FE so why we need of per client topic bcz message will always be file only and per client subscription will be handled by filter option in the subscription in filter we will provide clients uuid 4.can you please elaborate ack msg could be redelivered

Comment: if we don't stop the subscriber as you said in the second para we will get the second message immediately and that tool only processes one file at a time so in this scenario what should we do? and if we don't ack immediately and do ack after the task is done by TOOL then ordering of message is misbehaving can you please help us with this ?

Comment: But what if the crash happens literally right after the line `message.ack();`? Who sends the failed status? If you are using per-client topics, keep in mind the quota. With regard to redelivery, acks are best-effort and so under circumstances outside your control, acks may not be persisted and messages could be redelivered. To ensure you only get one message at a time, use flow control and set the max outstanding messages to 1, though this would require you to not ack messages until you processing finishes.

Comment: If you are having ordering issues when not acking, it is likely that you are seeing redeliveries and your subscribers perhaps aren't resilient to those. GCP support could tell the order of messages that were delivered and redelivered if you reach out to them and provide your project and subscription.

Comment: oh I got your point but 1. Tool is configured that way that when it crashes it sends status to `/listen` route see above code so in that we will configure that if error then tell the user to resend the file and we will again call `main()` to create subscriber handler again 2. we are using flow controller as option in subscription as shown above

Comment: what should I do to remove that immediate acking, may I hold the subscriber and when task is done (may take 1hr) then I ack() or anything like that? ,  but by doing this may be ordering key will not work? NOTE : WE can configure that TOOL to make GET or POST calls and one more thing the pricing of PubSub is based on message size or ??

Comment: Ordering keys work fine if you delay acking. Holding on to a message for an hour is not going to be great and could lead to duplicates, so your best bet is going to be to persist the message you need to operation on and then ack or just use GCS without involving Pub/Sub. With regard to pricing, I'd say it is best to treat that as a separate question as there are already a wide variety of topics covered in this answer.

Comment: we were doing that only that every 5 sec we delay the ack with 120 sec ? but when we increase that 5 sec to 1m or more then it behaves weirdly regarding file we are storing it on VM only so no worries there

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "behaves weirdly." As I mentioned, you might want to consider reaching out to support so they can look at your specific subscription.

Comment: behaves weirdly - means message send again (duplicate) / receiving  same message to both subscriber like that